# How do I display a button on the screen?

Tags: android, button, graphics, view

So I am making a game for Android that basically involves a space ship moving left and right on the screen (locked in portrait mode) that is trying to dodge objects flying at it from the top of the screen. I have a class GraphicsView (it extends View) that deals with all of the drawing and whatnot. I am trying to display two buttons on the button, one to move the ship to the left and one to move the ship to the right. I have this code strewn throughout:

```
Button mLeft;

mLeft = new Button (context);

mLeft.setX (0);
mLeft.setY (mDisplay.getHeight () - 64);
mLeft.setHeight (64);
mLeft.setWidth (64);
mLeft.setBackgroundColor (80000000);
mLeft.setText ("<");
```

Whenever I try to call any of these methods of mLeft above, my program crashes. I have tried commenting all of them out, then adding them back individually to see if any one of them won't crash, but ll of them do. I am able to do mLeft.draw (canvas) without the program crashing, but nothing shows up on the screen.

Any help on this would be very appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

did you add `mLeft.setOnClickListener()` . Also, for the `onDraw()`, did you add `invalidate()` at the end of the method?

Comment: I Just added mLeft.setOnClickListener (this) right after the mLeft = new Button (context), but it still crashes. I do have an invalidate at the very bottom of my onDraw method.

Comment: You need to make your class implement OnClickListener interface and you must override the onClick methoed, else you can do the following: `mLeft.setOnClickListener (new View.onClickListener{ //implement onClick{})`. Can you also show the onDraw()

Comment: I have implements View.OnClickListener, and an onClick (View view) method.

Comment: Did you try replacing `context` with `this` or `getApplicationContext`?

Comment: If you mean in the new Button argument, I just did. When I replace it with "this," it is an error. When I replace context with context.getApplicationContext (), it crashes still.

Comment: Can you replace it with the package name? Also, can you show me the LogCat for the first case and the onDraw method

Comment: Changing to the package name is just an error. Sure, the onDraw looks like


  protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas)
  {
    Paint background = new Paint ();
    background.setColor (getResources ().getColor (R.color.White));
    
    canvas.drawRect (0, 0, getWidth (), getHeight (), background);
    canvas.drawBitmap (mBgSprite.getBitmap (), null, mBgRect, background);
    canvas.drawRect (mButtonRect, background);
    
    mLeft.draw (canvas);
    
    mPlayerSprite.onDraw (canvas);
    super.onDraw (canvas);
    invalidate ();
  }

Comment: The logCat with just context as the argument says: 


12-04 02:53:46.418: D/ATRecorder(1213): com.htc.autotest.dlib.RecordEngine in loader dalvik.system.DexClassLoader@4052c9e8
12-04 02:53:51.313: I/dalvikvm(1213): Could not find method android.widget.Button.setX, referenced from method edu.pacificu.cs.Views.GraphicsView.<init>
12-04 02:53:51.313: W/dalvikvm(1213): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 37: Landroid/widget/Button;.setX (F)V

There's a lot more to it, mostly just fatal errors. Too long for pasting into here, It goes about 2000 characters over limit

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of setText("<"). Try changing that to something else.

Comment: I've tried commenting out just that line. Each of them causes it to crash.

Comment: And the LogCat always says 'Could not find method android.widget.Button.setX, referenced from method edu.pacificu.cs.Views.GraphicsView.<init>' Or whichever method is called first, instead of setX.